# Choosing a power supply for motor controlled by JD2912-1Z-12VDC relay

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, relay, dc-motor

I have a JD2912-1Z-12VDC relay that controls the flow of power to a 12VDC 50W motor and I'm trying to choose a suitable power supply.

Initially I thought the amperage the motor draws would be 50W / 12VDC = 4.167A, so I thought choosing a [12V 15A power supply](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09LVFT9YL) would more than suffice for my needs.

However, the numbers on the relay made me pause and I wanted to make sure I understood everything that is happening here.

Namely, [this relay](https://imgur.com/a/AkNe3Xd) is labeled as JD2912-1Z-12VDC but directly underneath it states 40A 14VDC.

1. Would I be correct in assuming that the 40A is overkill and I only need to choose a power supply with 4.167A in mind? Or could it be that this 40A capacity is to compensate for potential inrush current when the motor first starts?
2. Why are there 2 different voltage ratings for the relay? 12VDC and 14VDC?

Comment: It looks like a standard automotive type relay. I was unable to find the manufacturer of datasheet. The 40A is the maximum that the relay can handle. Find a power supply suitable for your motor.

Comment: Understood, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [this relay] is labeled as JD2912-1Z-12VDC but directly underneath it states 40A 14VDC

The 12VDC at the end of the part number is just that, part of the part number. The 14VDC after the 40A tells you that it should work properly up to 14VDC.

> Would I be correct in assuming that the 40A is overkill

Not necessarily. Motor manufacturers often publish figures for "locked rotor current". That is the current that will flow through the motor when the rotor is held stationary. This current can easily be six times the "rated" current of the motor. That is, the locked rotor current will typically burn out the motor if that condition persists for too long. A typical motor may be rated to withstand locked rotor current for 30 seconds, and some up to perhaps 120 seconds. However one thing to note about locked rotor current is that, more frequently than not, it is present for short time whenever a motor starts from a stationary condition. If your motor draws 4 A under normal load, it might draw 32 A at start up. (Of course your power supply might not be able to deliver 32 A). Relay contacts should be rated to handle the maximum current they might possibly see, even if it is transitory. Skimping on the contact ratings may lead to welded contacts, which in turn may lead to other failures.

> could it be that this 40A capacity is to compensate for potential inrush current when the motor first starts?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You need the power supply to be able to deliver the peak current the motor draws (Locked Rotor Amperes) **without** shutting down, or the power supply may go into foldback overcurrent protection and the motor will never run. This is not uncommon.

A 15A power supply may or may not be adequate, it depends on the motor.

There are no specific motor ratings given in the relay data so you can't really glean much information from that. The resistive rating is 560W and life is quoted as 100k (not sure I have 100% confidence in that at 40A).